# The bot is not working in Azure web chat after deploying back

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service

I tried to develop a bot locally (created in Azure) with dispatch model to integrate LUIS and a knowledge base in a single bot developed in Node.js. 
I used sample code available on [Github](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/14.nlp-with-dispatch) to get a response for each intent.
I deployed this bot back to Azure using Visual Studio Code but on the portal, web chat is not working. It just keeps loading, saying `Waiting for the bot to be ready`.

Here the `dispatchBot.js` file code -

```
const { ActivityHandler } = require('botbuilder');
const { LuisRecognizer, QnAMaker } = require('botbuilder-ai');

class DispatchBot extends ActivityHandler {
    /**
     * @param {any} logger object for logging events, defaults to console if none is provided
     */
    constructor(logger) {
        super();
        if (!logger) {
            logger = console;
            logger.log('[DispatchBot]: logger not passed in, defaulting to console');
        }

        const dispatchRecognizer = new LuisRecognizer({
            applicationId: process.env.LuisAppId,
            endpointKey: process.env.LuisAPIKey,
            endpoint: `https://${ process.env.LuisAPIHostName }.api.cognitive.microsoft.com`
        }, {
            includeAllIntents: true,
            includeInstanceData: true
        }, true);

        const qnaMaker = new QnAMaker({
            knowledgeBaseId: process.env.QnAKnowledgebaseId,
            endpointKey: process.env.QnAAuthKey,
            host: process.env.QnAEndpointHostName
        });

        this.logger = logger;
        this.dispatchRecognizer = dispatchRecognizer;
        this.qnaMaker = qnaMaker;

        this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
            this.logger.log('Processing Message Activity.');

            // First, we use the dispatch model to determine which cognitive service (LUIS or QnA) to use.
            const recognizerResult = await dispatchRecognizer.recognize(context);

            // Top intent tell us which cognitive service to use.
            const intent = LuisRecognizer.topIntent(recognizerResult);

            // Next, we call the dispatcher with the top intent.
            await this.dispatchToTopIntentAsync(context, intent, recognizerResult);

            await next();
        });

        this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
            const welcomeText = 'Type a greeting or a question about the weather to get started.';
            const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded;

            for (let member of membersAdded) {
                if (member.id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
                    await context.sendActivity(`Welcome to Dispatch bot ${ member.name }. ${ welcomeText }`);
                }
            }

            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next();
        });
    }

    async dispatchToTopIntentAsync(context, intent, recognizerResult) {
        switch (intent) {
        case 'l_luis':
            await this.processLuis(context, recognizerResult.luisResult);
            break;
        case 'q_sample-qna':
            await this.processSampleQnA(context);
            break;
        default:
            this.logger.log(`Dispatch unrecognized intent: ${ intent }.`);
            await context.sendActivity(`Dispatch unrecognized intent: ${ intent }.`);
            break;
        }
    }

    async processLuis(context, luisResult) {
        this.logger.log('processLuis');

        // Retrieve LUIS result for Process Automation.
        const result = luisResult.connectedServiceResult;
        const intent = result.topScoringIntent.intent;

        await context.sendActivity(`Luis top intent ${ intent }.`);
        await context.sendActivity(`Luis intents detected:  ${ luisResult.intents.map((intentObj) => intentObj.intent).join('\n\n') }.`);

        if (luisResult.entities.length > 0) {
            await context.sendActivity(`Luis entities were found in the message: ${ luisResult.entities.map((entityObj) => entityObj.entity).join('\n\n') }.`);
        }
    }

    async processSampleQnA(context) {
        this.logger.log('processSampleQnA');

        const results = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(context);

        if (results.length > 0) {
            await context.sendActivity(`${ results[0].answer }`);
        } else {
            await context.sendActivity('Sorry, could not find an answer in the Q and A system.');
        }
    }
}

module.exports.DispatchBot = DispatchBot;
```

Here is `app.js` file code -

```
const path = require('path');
const restify = require('restify');
var { BotFrameworkAdapter} = require('botbuilder');
const { DispatchBot } = require('./bots/dispatchBot');
var botbuilder_azure = require('botbuilder-azure');

const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
require('dotenv').config({ path: ENV_FILE });

const connector = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});

connector.onTurnError = async (context, error) => {
    console.error(`\n [onTurnError]: ${ error }`);
    await context.sendActivity(`Oops. Something went wrong!`);
};
var tableName = 'botdata';
var azureTableClient = new botbuilder_azure.AzureTableClient(tableName, process.env['AzureWebJobsStorage']);
var tableStorage = new botbuilder_azure.AzureBotStorage({ gzipData: false }, azureTableClient);

// Pass in a logger to the bot. For this sample, the logger is the console, but alternatives such as Application Insights and Event Hub exist for storing the logs of the bot.
const logger = console;

// Create the main dialog.
let bot = new DispatchBot(logger);

let server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function() {
    console.log(`\n${ server.name } listening to ${ server.url }`);
});

server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    // Route received a request to adapter for processing
    connector.processActivity(req, res, async (turnContext) => {
        // route to bot activity handler.
        await bot.run(turnContext);
    });
});
```

When I try running this bot on Visual studio code, the program executes successfully and I am getting the restify port address. I am not able to test in Emulator because it is not working due to some errors in emulator.. 
Any help or suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: What errors are you getting in Emulator? (I know you said it's not related, but it probably is)

Comment: Emulator errors - `Failed to spawn ngrokpanic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference github.com/inconshreveable`   and then `Cannot post activity. Unauthorized` error.

Comment: Can you reinstall your emulator and try again? You will need to make sure that your bot works locally before you deploy it to azure.